# Choose BSD or sys5 style when creating file in linux

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, bsd, systems-programming

When I create file in linux default group owner becomes gid of process which creates file. If I add SGID to parent directory file will inherit parent directory owner group. Also I can change fs mount options to behave either like sys5 or like BSD.

What if I want to choose this option regardless directory permissions and fs mount options? Is there c function option or syscall parameter which allows you to choose group owner?

```
$ find . -ls
   262    4 drwxrwxr-x   4 devops   devops       4096 Apr 24 18:01 .    
   999    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 devops   root         4096 Apr 24 18:03 ./dir1
  6093    4 drwxrwsr-x   2 devops   root         4096 Apr 24 18:03 ./dir2
$ touch dir1/file dir2/file
$ find . -ls
   262    4 drwxrwxr-x   4 devops   devops       4096 Apr 24 18:01 .
   999    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 devops   root         4096 Apr 24 18:04 ./dir1
  5576    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 devops   devops          0 Apr 24 18:04 ./dir1/file
  6093    4 drwxrwsr-x   2 devops   root         4096 Apr 24 18:04 ./dir2
  6094    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 devops   root            0 Apr 24 18:04 ./dir2/file
$
```

And I wish to have something like that:

```
$ mytouch -s BSD  dir1/file1
$ mytouch -s sys5 dir1/file2
$ find dir1 -ls
   999    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 devops   root         4096 Apr 24 18:10 dir1
  6213    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 devops   root            0 Apr 24 18:10 dir1/file1
  6214    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 devops   devops          0 Apr 24 18:10 dir1/file2
$
```

Comment: Code, please. Context is important. If you really care about permissions, `chown()` and `chmod()` do the same thing as their command-line friends. Depending on sticky bits is really hacky and I'd strongly discourage it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are, you can't.

The implementation of sticky bits exists entirely within the kernel, and there are no options to `open()` or `creat()`  which control how it operates.

Your program could conceivably call `chown()` to manually reset the group of the file after creating it. However, this would only work reliably if your process is running as root, or as a member of the group that owns the parent directory.